# Is wired Ethernet via USB adapter possible on the Google Pixel 2 phone, and in that case how? (NOTE: NOT the Pixel 2 XL!)

Tags: reverse-tether, google-pixel-2

**Simple question:**

**Did ANYONE get Ethernet connectivity via USB adapter to work on the Google Pixel 2 phone? (NOTE: NOT the Pixel 2 XL!)**

**(and in that case, using which USB-to-Ethernet adapter?)**

It's apparently working fine on all other Pixel phone models:

- Pixel
  (https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/5seqah/ethernet_over_otg_on_pixel/)
- Pixel XL
  (https://pixelmantras.com/google-pixel-pixel-xl-ethernet-connection-setup/)
- Pixel 2 XL
  (https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-2-xl/how-to/wired-ethernet-speeds-t3702289)

But for some strange reason the web/google currently seems clinically sanitized from ANY results, or even questions, regarding ethernet connectivity on the Google Pixel 2 phone?!

A number of people must have tried this, let alone asked about it before me, right? And out of these, someone must at least have gotten hold of some kind of more definitive answers?

*PS. I already tried the "Plugable USB 2.0 OTG Micro-B to 10/100 Ethernet Adapter" (https://plugable.com/products/usb2-otge100/) on it myself (which is an adapter that seems to work on many other phone models), without any success. :-( (yes, I used a USB micro-B to micro-C wire adapter to be able to fit it into the USB-C on the Pixel 2)*

Comment: The net could simply be clinically sanitized from any Pixel 2 (sans XL) purchases - just kidding. Try ones that work on P2XL, ask the forum/Reddit members for exact model if necessary. Doubt the set of drivers integrated in the two would be different.

Comment: They are on the contrary quite likely indeed to have completely different chipsets/drivers integrated, since the two devices (Pixel 2 and Pixel 2 XL) are manufactured by two completely different mobile phone designer companies (HTC and LG). For example, the ethernet adapter that I mention above having already tested **does** work on the Pixel 2 XL, but apparently not on the Pixel 2. :-(

Comment: Different chipset indeed, but I've thought that under the supervision of Google the innards would've been similar (especially considering the addition of Project Treble). Oh well...

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)